# Is it a good style to modify a preprocessor macro in the code?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some code that defines the macro VALUE1. In a portion of the code, I need that value to change.
Is this the proper way to do it?

```
#define VALUE1 123
...
#define VALUE1 345
...
// Reset the original value
#define VALUE1 123
```

The compiler (GCC) gives me a warning about the redefinition.

Comment: Why not have an `enum` with various values ?

Comment: @Mahesh I need it for conditional compilation, so I need to talk to the preprocessor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gives you a warning because most of times it's unwanted: you're assigning a value to an existing macro because you didn't know it exists.

When you have to do it IMO is much better to be more explicit (to let the preprocessor know it's not an error and to make it clear to human readers too):

```
#define VALUE 1

#undef VALUE
#define VALUE 2

#undef VALUE
#define VALUE 3
```

Just for information you may even disable that warning using  `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` but even in that case you'd better to write something to explain the reason.

That said you may consider to review your design, I can't say something better without more information about your code (or about what you want to achieve) but if you need such trick probably a little **refactoring** will make everything much more clear.

Comment: Adriano, I thought the #undef was implicit when I redefined the macro. Grazie!